# FIXED Html table for horizontal menu (3 rows)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[3 rows topmenu table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paRW2.jpg) Hi guys
Attached is an image of an html table
I would like to use this table on my website as a fixed horizontal topmenu
This menu will be inserted using 'Include' statement right under the body tag
my website is working fine with this table inside a horizontal frame on top
Frames websites are no longer practical so  need I to convert
I am  looking for any code (css/html/JS) that would help me achieve that goal
Thanks
Dory

Comment: You should use rows and columns to achieve that with the help of bootstrap grid system https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt recreating this layout using flexbox.

(if you do want to see this thing in action, it's better to view it through codepen)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}


.flex-grow {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.justify-content-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.justify-content-end {
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.justify-content-start {
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.border-right-0 {
  border-right: none !important;
}

.nav-ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nav-ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.w-100 {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.mr-2 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.color-white {
  color: white;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container bg-yellow flex-column">
  <div class="flex-container bg-yellow">
    <ul class="nav-ul flex-container">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Faq</li>
      <li>Login/Log Off</li>
      <li>Register</li>
      <li>My-Account</li>
      <li>Pallet-Rate</li>
      <li class="border-right-0">Price-Lists</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container bg-red w-100 justify-content-between">
    <div class="flex-container flex-grow justify-content-start">
      <div class="flex-container mr-2 ml-2 flex-wrap">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container color-white">
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold">My Website.com (Wholesale ONLY)</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-grow justify-content-end">
      <div class="flex-container mr-2 ml-2">
        <h5 class="bg-yellow">XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container bg-yellow">
    <ul class="nav-ul flex-container">
      <li>Specials</li>
      <li>Shopping-Cart</li>
      <li>Categories</li>
      <li>Hold-Order</li>
      <li>Search</li>
      <li>My-Items</li>
      <li class="border-right-0">Help</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/XyqgGx?editors=1100)